# Power-shell script for AD

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to get power-shell script for AD which will be provide like: Name : WINNB0100    ManagedBy:  rumi

Comment: Your question is not clear, add more information and what you have already done, SO is not a code writing service you know...

Answer (score 1):

This will provide you with what you ask for, if this is not what you are looking for please rephrase your question and provide more detailed information.

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties ManagedBy | Select Name, ManagedBy
```